# Why is MVC not checking my data annotations?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following set:

```
public class Account : AuditableTable, IAccount  
{
}
public class Product : AuditableTable  
{
}
public abstract class AuditableTable

    [Range(0, 99, ErrorMessage = "Position must be between 0 and 99.")]
    [DisplayName("Position")]
    public int? Position { get; set; }
```

In my view:

```
        <div class="adm_td0">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Account.Position, new { size = 4 })
        </div>
        <div class="adm_td0">
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Account.Position)
        </div>
```

When I enter a number greater than 99 the number is accepted. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? When I check my source code I see

```
<input id="Product_Position" type="text" value="24788" size="4" name="Product.Position" data-val-range-min="0" data-val-range-max="99" data-val-range="Position must be between 0 and 99." data-val-number="The field Position must be a number." data-val="true">
```

But there's no check on the page OR on the server.

On the page I have included the following Javascripts:

```
"~/Scripts/jquery/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"
```

I think I am missing something so there's no client validation. BUT should there still not be server validation?

If I do validation on the client then do I need to include ALL of the following:

```
"~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"
"~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"
"~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"
```

Comment: I just added it now. The whole code is very large so I just added the bit for the position input field.

Comment: from html helper shouldn't ur input name be `Account.Position` instead of `Product.Position`

Comment: Yes you need to include those files.....they are what causes the validations to occur

Comment: Which files should I use. I am confused as it seems like something changed with the files that are needed. Do I need the ajax one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your View code to this :

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Account.Position)
```

It should work

Also, You need to include

> "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"
>
> "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"
>
> "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"

Otherwise your validations wont work on that page

Comment: `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Account.Position, new { size = 4 })` should work as well. `EditorFor` does not affect unobtrusive attributes but the type of input to be rendered. I believe problem lies somewhere else

Comment: Yes you're correct. It did just change the type. Still doesn't work. I added some additional class information to the question. This is strange but I am wondering if the server validation is not working because this field is inherited from the other class and not directly added in the Product and Account classes. Having said that when I look at my page I see that there's some validation been added there even though that's not working properly either.

Comment: check the updated answer....You haven't included those scripts that's why the validation isn't happening

Comment: But should it still not happen on the server if those scripts are missing on the client?

Comment: No, they won't...the form will be submitted and sql exception will be raised if the matching column in database has some validation or else the record will be added

Comment: @Samantha2, make sure you also include in the appSettings of the web.config
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/> 
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>